# converting android map v1 to google android map v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I Have A Android Map IN Eclipse Using Api Key v1 and Now I am Trying To Convert it Into v2. But I am Total Confused to do it easily.A Bit Effort I Have Done I Got Map Api key v2 and Also Updated mY SDk According To That e-g Google Play Services etc and Also Changed My Manifest File According To that.Now Its Time To actualy Changed My Source Code Which is Showing My Map and the Markers From JSON Api.Here is all About My App
**Layout File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GMapsActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:width="150dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pass"
        android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
        android:text="@string/log" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="map3.pkg.pkg"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0"
      android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <permission android:name="map2.pkg.pkg.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"  android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application 
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name="map3.pkg.pkg.GMapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBxjGroO8h6KXAmxEGyTwR-MXqjLnYwU_k" />

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Source File**

This Code is Actualy For v1 and Now I Want to Convert it Into v3

```
package map3.pkg.pkg;

import java.util.List;

//import android.R;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import map2.pkg.pkg.R;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;

public class GMapsActivity extends MapActivity {

private MapView mapView;
EditText password;
Button   login;
TextView vwpass;

JSONArray jArray;
String result = null;
InputStream is = null;
StringBuilder sb=null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);


password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);       
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v)
            {   
                if(password.getText().toString().equals("tsml")) {
                mapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                password.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "invalid password - try again",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
      ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      try{
           HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://221.120.216.52/a/map.php");
           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
           HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
           is = entity.getContent();
           }catch(Exception e){
               Log.i("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
          }
      //convert response to string
      try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
             sb = new StringBuilder();
             sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

             String line="0";
             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
              }
              is.close();
              result=sb.toString();
              }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
              }
//paring data
double LAT;
double LANG;
String INFO;
//result="[{\"lat\":\"31.5079616\",\"lang\":\"74.3376768\",\"info\":\" AQ Corolla (LZA 516)\",\"groupID\":\"Lahore\"},{\"lat\":\"31.5260192\",\"lang\":\"74.3768128\",\"info\":\" LC1 Corolla (LEA 6739)\",\"groupID\":\"Lahore\"}]";
try{
      jArray = new JSONArray(result);
      JSONObject json_data=null;
      for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
             json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
             LAT=json_data.getDouble("lat");
             LANG=json_data.getDouble("lang");
             INFO=json_data.getString("info");


//Overlay code
List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
        CustomItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

        //GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitudeE6, longitudeE6);
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(LAT * 1e6),(int)(LANG * 1e6));
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Shakarganj", INFO);
        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

        MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

        mapController.animateTo(point);
        mapController.setZoom(6);

//Overlay code

         }
      }
      catch(JSONException e1){
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Vehicles Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
}
```

It is Just Getting Point From A URL and Convert it into a String Then Parse Using JSON and then Displays on Map.Plz any One Help Me that How Can I Now Convert this Code To Display the map of api v3.Plz Help

Answer (score 4):

If you are already able to display a map using google play service (Maps API V2) you've already done a lot of the work.

Second, please that the time to look at the [Google Documentation for the new Android Maps V2 API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/). They cover most cases very well....

Third, Your JSON code is not impacted. The biggest change in the API as far as you are concerned is the marker mgmt.

You can change this original code where you are adding a single marker to the map

```
List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
CustomItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

    //GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitudeE6, longitudeE6);
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(LAT * 1e6),(int)(LANG * 1e6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Shakarganj", INFO);
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

    MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

    mapController.animateTo(point);
    mapController.setZoom(6);
```

With this

```
LatLng markerPosition = new LatLng(LAT ,LANG );
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(markerPosition
                         .title("Shakarganj")
                         .snippet(INFO));
```

No need to work with overlays anymore.

If you want to animate to the marker you use the animateCamera method on the map:

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(markerPosition);
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

instead of using the mapController.